# How to detect in Android that WIFI is ON, but unreachable?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, connectivity

Does anyone know how to programatically detect in Android that wifi is unreachable?
I've got an app running where I am able to easily detect type of network connection and whether is on or not (NetworkInfo class), but I can't detect that wifi is ON, but I am out of reach on the other side of building, so there is no internet. Network info keeps on saying that type of network is WIFI, isConnected = true, getDetailedState = CONNECTED, so these don't help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "wifi is on but unreachable?" Do you mean that you're connected to a network but can't send any data through it or that the wifi is on but there are no networks to connect to?

Comment: yes, I mean that I switched WIFI ON on my phone and then walked far away from router, so I can't browse web pages, send data, etc... in this case, NetworkInfo still reports CONNECTED. I am using this code:

`ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();`

Comment: You could possibly try detecting it by pinging a server and seeing if the ping times out?

Comment: Hello. Have you solve the problem? That is we can connect to the router through wifi, but the connection between router and internet is broken. How can you detect this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Detect WIFI is connected or on. If wifi is not connected to any INTERNET connection then display message that "`WIFI is unreachable or no INTERNET connection.`"

For checking WIFI is connected use following code.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work. This is the situation which I've got already. mWifi reports CONNECTED. Problem is as I have described that I am out of reach, even though my Wifi functionality (or have to put it) is switched ON.

Comment: Then you have to call this method at specific time.

Comment: that's what I do. I call it in a moment when I am out of reach (wifi icon is just a little dot) and inspect the logs.

Comment: thanks, looks like signal strength is the one to monitor/detect in this case.